# How do you exit the console in Battlefield 4?

Tags: pc, battlefield-4

I accidently opened the console with "B". Afterwards I was unable to get out of the console again until I killed the task.

**How do I get out of the console without closing the game?**

Comment: Did you try ESC or tilde (~)?

Comment: Should be tilde, that's what it is in BF3

Comment: Both didn't work.

Comment: Try Shift and B (edit: B? what a weird place for console).

Answer (score 9):

The same happened to me and I almost lost it...

You have to press the key left to the "1". On some keyboard layout it's the tilde key.
It also happened that I had to hit it multiple times until the console disappeared.

[image]

Comment: When the console opens you can only shut it down if there is no text in the console input field. because you open it accidently most of times you also accidently put `wwwsswwaa` in the input field of the console. You have to clear it first and then you can close the console with `

Comment: @botenvouwer never strafes to the right ;-)